# AFrame VR experience in iOS app using UIWebview?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, aframe, webvr

Is there a way to pack an AFrame webVR experience into an iOS AppStore application? using UIWebView or the like? Would it work fully with "VR/cardboard/accelerometers" or only with the users "dragging the 360 3D scene with fingers touches" to look around?

Or is there all sorts of fluctuating iOS/AppStore restrictions that makes it impossible or impractical?

Answer (score 0):

UIWebView is deprecated, you can do it with a WKWebView, something like this :

```swift
webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration())
webView?.frame = containerView.bounds
webView?.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
webView?.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
webView?.configuration.requiresUserActionForMediaPlayback = false
webView?.configuration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
webView?.configuration.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
webView?.configuration.preferences.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
webView?.navigationDelegate = self
webView?.uiDelegate = self
```